# What is the reverse expression of 'is divisible by'?

Tags: expressions

When I can say following expression with two numbers, `a` and `b`,

`a` is divisible by `b`, e.g. `24` is divisible by `6`.

How can I say it in a reversed manner?

Say,

`b` is ... ... `a`, e.g. `6` is ... ... `24`.

Comment: 'b' is *a factor of* 'a'?

Comment: b is a factor of a, and 6 is a factor of 24. (Also, a is a multiple of b, and 24 is a multiple of 6.) I think that this might be more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because better on math.stackexchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

24 is divisible by 6.

6 **is a factor of** 24.

[factor
mathematics](https://www.britannica.com/science/factor-mathematics)

> factor, in mathematics, a number or algebraic expression that divides another number or expression evenly—i.e., with no remainder. For example, 3 and 6 are factors of 12 because 12 ÷ 3 = 4 exactly and 12 ÷ 6 = 2 exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, 6 ***divides*** 24.

(This might be useful if you're teaching division and haven't yet introduced the word "factor".)